# "No Steam config online" error when installing Skyrim on PC

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I just bought Skyrim on PC and when I try to install it I have to update Steam. When I try, a pop up says "no Steam config online".

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried updating Steam?

Comment: It sounds like the Steam servers are overloaded- presumably due to everyone else trying to update Steam. Try it again now- does it work?

Comment: Another, perhaps easier way, is to uninstall steam (make sure to clean out the /Steam folder) and make a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by necessary Steam servers being unavailable. You can either [download the Steam installer directly](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) and run that or wait for the servers to become available.